# How can create browser page with browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can create browser page with browser ? Like for example test environment provided in w3schools.com, we can not see the code

Comment: You mean like the `Try it Yourself Editor` on their home page that currently returns a 404 error? LOL, http://w3fools.com/. It's pretty easy. To achieve this *effect* just create a link (`<a>`) tag to a non-existing document on your server.

Comment: Save the data they submit into the field as a session variable and have the page load that session variable onto the page when the page refreshes. Or google it, ya know.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. If you can edit it to be more specific, please flag it for moderator attention to be reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

An iFrame is what W3Schools uses, but you can also do it without one. The design of the actual page is up to you, but here's the basic framework of doing it in plain Javascript/HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateDiv() {
    myTextArea = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
    contentDiv = document.getElementById('contentDiv');

    contentDiv.innerHTML = myTextArea.value;
}
</script>

<textarea rows="8" cols="60" id="myTextArea"></textarea><br />
<div id="contentDiv"></div><br />
<input type="button" value="Update!" onclick="updateDiv()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iframe to create "another browser page". See [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) for more information

Comment: Please refrain from referring people to w3schools, [see w3fools.com for why](http://w3fools.com). Although the OP has already mentioned them, and what you link to might be correct, there is a lot of information on that site which isn't

Comment: Yeah but at least it's basic and easy to understand fro newbie

Comment: And that's the problem, a newbie doesn't know better... and sending to a site that is full of mis-information isn't going to help. The page you've referenced might be correct, but you're giving the impression the site is trust-worthy... which it isn't

Comment: Ok, I'll noticed that. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways but nearly all are based on a ContentEditable component in the browser.

ContentEditable is a low-level feature. Higher-level support is available through Javascript libraries (eg, [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)).

Demo with source: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable/

Microsoft Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Mozilla Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable